# Spring JMS & Websphere MQ: Message is not picked up by the application

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have an application which uses spring-jms, websphere mq, websphere application server 7. 
On a user interaction, I am putting a message in a Queue A. I have a Listener-A(using DefaultMessageListenerContainer in springframework) which picks up the message. That listener-A is supposed to process it and send a response to Queue A-Response. In that process, I am trying to put another message on a different Queue B for which I have a different Listener-B  defined. But for some reason, after the message is put on Queue B, the Listener-B is not picking it up. 
When I try to put the message manually on the Queue B, Listener-B picks the message and processes it, but when I try the above mentioned scenario, it doesn't work. Also, when I comment out the code that puts a message on Queue B in the Listener-A, then the Listener-A processes the message and sends a response back to Queue A-Response.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit: Added code

Here is the spring configuration that I have

```
    <bean id="jmsListener-Parent" abstract="true"
    class="MyJmsServiceExporter">
    <property name="messageTimeToLive" value="60000" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager" />

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor">
    <property name="workManagerName" value="wm/default" />
</bean>

<bean name="jmsListenerContainer-Parent"
      abstract="true"
      class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />  
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor" />
</bean>

<bean id="FirstService-Listener" parent="jmsListener-Parent">
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="FirstService" />
    <property name="service" ref="FirstServiceImpl" />
    <property name="messageConverter" ref="MyMessageConverter" />
</bean>

<bean id="SecondService-Listener" parent="jmsListener-Parent">
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="SecondService" />
    <property name="service" ref="SecondServiceImpl" />
    <property name="messageConverter" ref="MyMessageConverter" />
</bean>

<bean name="FirstService-ListenerContainer"
      parent="jmsListenerContainer-Parent">
    <property name="destination" ref="FirstQueue-Request" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="FirstService-Listener" />
</bean>

<bean name="SecondService-ListenerContainer"
      parent="jmsListenerContainer-Parent">
    <property name="destination" ref="SecondQueue-Request" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="SecondService-Listener" />
</bean>

<bean id="FirstService-Client"
      class="MyJmsServiceInvoker">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />          
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="FirstService" />
    <property name="messageConverter" ref="MyMessageConverter" />
    <property name="queue" ref="FirstQueue-Request" />
    <property name="responseQueue" ref="FirstQueue-Response" />
    <property name="timeToLive" value="60000" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="60000" />            
</bean>  

<bean id="SecondService-Client"
      class="MyJmsServiceInvoker">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />          
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="SecondService" />
    <property name="messageConverter" ref="MyMessageConverter" />
    <property name="queue" ref="SecondQueue-Request" />
    <property name="responseQueue" ref="SecondQueue-Response" />
    <property name="timeToLive" value="60000" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="60000" />            
</bean>
```

MyJmsServiceInvoker(extends JmsInvokerProxyFactoryBean) methods:

```
protected Message doExecuteRequest(
        Session session,
        Queue queue,
        Message requestMessage) 
throws JMSException {
    MessageProducer producer = null;
    MessageConsumer consumer = null;
    Message responseMessage = null;
    String correlationId = null;
    String responseSelector = null;

    try {
        LOG.info("CmsJmsServiceInvoker::doExecuteRequest");
        requestMessage.setJMSType("TEXT");
        requestMessage.setJMSReplyTo(responseQueue);
        requestMessage.setJMSExpiration(this.getTimeToLive());

        producer = session.createProducer(queue);

        if (isPersistentMessage()) {
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
        } else {
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
        }

        producer.setTimeToLive(getTimeToLive());

        LOG.info("Sending requestMessage.");
        producer.send(requestMessage);

        correlationId = requestMessage.getJMSMessageID();
        responseSelector = 
            "JMSCorrelationID=\'" + correlationId + "\'";

        consumer = session.createConsumer(responseQueue, responseSelector);

        long timeout = getReceiveTimeout();

        LOG.info("Awaiting response.");
        if (timeout > 0) {
            responseMessage = consumer.receive(timeout);
        } else {
            responseMessage = consumer.receive();
        }

        if (responseMessage == null) {
            LOG.info("Timeout encountered.");
            throw new RuntimeException("Timeout");
        }
    } catch (JMSSecurityException jse) {
        LOG.error("SecurityException encountered.", jse);
        throw new RuntimeException("JMS SecurityException, jse");

    } finally {
        JmsUtils.closeMessageConsumer(consumer);
        JmsUtils.closeMessageProducer(producer);
    }

    LOG.info("Returning response Message.");
    return responseMessage;      
}
```

MyJmsServiceExporter(extends JmsInvokerServiceExporter) methods:

```
protected void writeRemoteInvocationResult(Message requestMessage,
                                           Session session,
                                           RemoteInvocationResult result)
throws JMSException {
    MessageProducer producer = null;
    Message response = null;
    if (requestMessage.getJMSReplyTo() == null) {
        LOG.debug("Async:  This request will not have a "
                  + "response since there is no reply queue in the "
                  + "JMS header.");
        return;
    }

    producer = session.createProducer(requestMessage.getJMSReplyTo());

    try {
        response = createResponseMessage(requestMessage, session,
                result);
        producer.setTimeToLive(getMessageTimeToLive());
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

        if (persistentMessage) {
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
        }
        producer.send(response);

        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("Sending response message.");
            LOG.debug(response);
        }
    } finally {
        if (producer != null) {
            JmsUtils.closeMessageProducer(producer);
        }
    }
}

protected Message createResponseMessage(
        Message request,
        Session session,
        RemoteInvocationResult result) 
throws JMSException {
    Message response = null;
    String correlation = null;

    correlation = request.getJMSCorrelationID();

    response = super.createResponseMessage(request, session, result);
    if (correlation == null) {
        correlation = request.getJMSMessageID();
    }

    response.setJMSCorrelationID(correlation);
    response.setJMSExpiration(getMessageTimeToLive());

    return response;
}  


public void onMessage(Message requestMessage, Session session)
        throws JMSException {
    RemoteInvocationResult result = null;

    try {
        RemoteInvocation invocation = readRemoteInvocation(requestMessage);

        if (invocation != null) {
            result = 
                invokeAndCreateResult(invocation, getProxyForService());
        }
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        if (result == null) {
            result = new RemoteInvocationResult(throwable);
        }

        throwable.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        writeRemoteInvocationResult(requestMessage, session, result);
        // JmsUtils.commitIfNecessary(session);
    }
}
```

FirstServiceImpl class has a saveText method which is invoked when a message is put in FirstQueue-Request. In that method, I am trying to call SecondService method: validateText(textmessage). This message is put on SecondQueue-Request but never read.

Comment: You need to provide much more detail for a question like this. If you are using transactions, the send to queue-B will not be committed (available for receipt) until the initial transaction is committed. If the request from queue-A is waiting for a response to the message sent to queue-B, it will never happen. If this is the case, you need to start a new transaction for the queue-B interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't commit session after message send.

It seems to me that you are trying to implement request-reply-by-correlationid logic while at same time working with transacted resources and manual session handling; all within same method (doExecuteRequest() or writeRemoteInvocationResult()). That's a lot of stuff for 20 lines of code. This kind of code is usually used with temporary queues..

Do you really need to write code on session level? Is there a reason why you couldn't just use jmsTemplate to send message, and messageListenerContainer to receive reply?